# Standard SQL: LEFT JOIN by two conditions using BETWEEN

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, left-join

I have the following query in BigQuery:

```
#Standard SQL

SELECT *
FROM `Table_1`     
LEFT JOIN `Table_2` ON (timestamp BETWEEN TimeStampStart AND TimeStampEnd)
```

But I get the following Error:

```
Error: LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.
```

If I use JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN, it works, but I want to keep all the rows from Table_1 (so also the ones which aren't matched to Table_2)

How to achieve this?

Comment: What is the relation between table 1 and table 2 ?  ,if there is no relation i would prefer using a Union clause instead of a join which is irrelevant in this context

Comment: Table 1 contains a column with timestamps (and some other variables), while Table 2 contains also some other variables plus two columns with timestamps (one which indicates the starting time and the other indicates the ending time). So I would like to merge those two tables such that when the timestamp of Table_1 lies between the starting and ending time, the variables of both tables are joined/merged.

Comment: ok, can you try SELECT *
FROM `Table_1`     
LEFT JOIN `Table_2`  ON(table1.timestamp >= table2.TimeStampStart AND table1.timestamp <=  table2.TimeStampEnd)

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: What did you learn from the many hits googling your error message with & without tags? [ask] Also, left join returns inner join rows union all unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. So you can union the separate parts. Surely doing that's a faq if not obvious. PS Please clarify via post edits, not comments. PS Re replacing between by ineqalities: [BigQuery does support inequality joins now - make sure to uncheck the "use legacy SQL option".](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37141994/3404097)

Comment: @philipxy the above query produces the error with the "updated" SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is absolutely stupid... but the same query will work if you add a condition that matches a column from table1 with a column from table2:

```
WITH Table_1 AS (
  SELECT CAST('2018-08-15' AS DATE) AS Timestamp, 'Foo' AS Foo
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CAST('2018-09-15' AS DATE), 'Foo'
), Table_2 AS (
  SELECT CAST('2018-08-14' AS DATE) AS TimeStampStart, CAST('2018-08-16' AS DATE) AS TimeStampEnd, 'Foo' AS Bar
)
SELECT *
FROM Table_1
LEFT JOIN Table_2 ON Table_1.Foo = Table_2.Bar AND Table_1.Timestamp BETWEEN Table_2.TimeStampStart AND Table_2.TimeStampEnd
```

See if you have additional matching criteria that you can use (like another column that links table1 and table2 on equality).

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks!

Comment: Brilliant, this answer made my day!

Answer (score 1):

A LEFT JOIN is always equivalent to the UNION of :

the INNER JOIN between the same two arguments on the same join predicate, and
the set of rows from the first argument for which no matching row is found (and properly extended with null values for all columns retained from the second argument)

That latter portion can be written as

SELECT T1.*, null as T2_C1, null as T2_C2, ...
  FROM T1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE )

So if you spell out the UNION you should be able to get there.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. This works for me in standard SQL:

```
select *
from (select 1 as x) a left join
     (select 2 as a, 3 as b) b
     on a.x between b.a and b.b
```

I suspect you are using legacy SQL.  Such switch to standard SQL.  (And drop the parentheses after the `between`.)

The problem is:

```
#(Standard SQL)#
```

This doesn't do anything.  Use:

```
#StandardSQL
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't fully understand what 1,2 and 3 represent in your query. I only added #(Standard SQL)# in my example to clarify I use StandardSQL, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @MC09 . . . That query is  just a demonstration that the syntax is accepted in Standard SQL.  Your problem is that the query is interpreted as Legacy SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Hi as per the documentation, "(" has a special meaning, so please try without the brackets.

`SELECT * FROM Table_1 
LEFT JOIN Table_2 ON Table_1.timestamp >= Table_2.TimeStampStart AND Table_1.timestamp <= Table_2.TimeStampEnd`

[Documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax)

Comment: Still the same error message. Is there any other way to achieve the same goal without using LEFT JOIN ?